# Change image attibute to using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a block of code through which I am changing the title of input as span. next to that is my image though which is set as display hidden.

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" name="email" class="w_def_text" id="email" title="Email*" />
  <img width="27" height="27" src="images/error.png" alt="Error">
</div>
```

I have changed this tiltle as span using jquery. Now I am sending input values on blur event.

like

```
$('#email').blur(function() {
var email = $('#email').val();
(1.)   $(this).next('img').show().html('<img width="80" height="27" src="images/dot.gif" >');
$.post('showuserstatus.php', {
    emailid: email
}, function(data) {
//$('#erroremail').show().html(data);
(2.)   $(this).next().next().html(data);

   });
});
```

At both the point I wish to change src of image, that is while sending response. And after receiving response.

**NOTE :** I have used .next.next because I have span in between both. So second next is for image.

Comment: $(this).next().next().html(data); here this will point to current document not email input.

Comment: yup...but as I am using this on blur of email so it work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$(".field img").attr("src", "images/dot.gif");
```

Comment: It should be `$("img").attr("src", "images/dot.gif");` As I don't have `$(".field img")` class.